# Read From Pipe in Bash Script

Tags: bash

I've got a Bash script which is only ever going to be invoked via a pipe.  I'm curious what's the best way to read the data from the pipe?  The command will look like:

```
$ output_gen | process
```

My script is process.  This is not homework, but it is a learning exercise.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. The input will just appear on stdin as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your program is receiving data from a pipeline, it's received via stdin. To read from stdin, use the `read` builtin. Here is an example:

myprog:

```
while read -r line; do 
    <something with "$line">
done
```

command:

```
printf 'foo\nbar\n' | ./myprog
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: You can use the ‘**read command**’ with a “**while loop**” to read from a pipe within a bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat names.txt | while read name; do
echo "$name"
done
```

Method 2: You can use the ‘**read command**’ to read from a **pipe** within a script in the terminal. For example,

```
echo “Hello World!”  | { read name; echo “msg=$name”; }
```

Method 3: If you want to read a command through pipe, you need a script like this:
func.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
function read_stdin()
{
  cat > file.txt
}
read_stdin
```

This will take any command as input and redirect the output to file.txt. Try running:

```
date|./func.sh
```